# yarn create next-app returns error, but create react-app works just fine

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to start a nextjs project, and as of the documentation i'm running

```
yarn create next-app appname
```

But this command executes and returns an error.

[image]

Can someone help me fix this? And please, explain why this error occurs so in the future i'll know how to deal with it.

Many thanks!

Comment: I am having same problem but my windows device says "Running Scripts is not allowed"

Answer (score 2):

Noticed that the username contains a space, and that originates the error.
Changing the windows username to a single thing without any spaces fixed the issue.

Comment: Good catch. That sounds like a bug in the next.js Yarn commandlet. Might be worth reporting that to them.